# Accessing self from a ctype callback function in Python?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I want to be able to call self from inside the callback function.

```
class MyClass():
    def myMethod(self):
        def myCallback(p1):
            print "Callback called!"
            # here I want to do something with self!

        CALLBACK_x = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint32)
        somedll.setCallback(CALLBACK_x(cbFileRefDone), 0)
```

The DWORD parameter from the the callback function is not used.

How can I access self?

Comment: I think that I could pass `ctypes.py_object(self)` as a parameter but I don't know how to get it back as a python object in the callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` should already be available in `myCallback`. Since it's created inside a function, it has access to the enclosing function's variables, including `self`. These variables are actually stored with the inner function in what's called a *closure,* so they stick around even after the enclosing function returns. Here's a minimal example:

```
class C(object):
   def f(self):
     def g():
        print self
     return g

c = C()
g = c.f()
g()
>>> <__main__.C object at 0x02AED1F0>
```

Comment: See [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/) for details on scoping in closures.  `self` should always be in scope of the nested function because it was passed as an argument to the `f` method.  Variables local to `f` may not be accessible without the `nonlocal` keyword, which wasn't added until Python 3.

Comment: @Nathan: Good information in that PEP, thanks for linking it. I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass():
    def myMethod(self):
        def myCallback(p1):
            self = ctypes.cast(p1, ctypes.py_object).value
            print "Callback called!"
            # here I want to do something with self!

        CALLBACK_x = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_uint32)
        somedll.setCallback(CALLBACK_x(cbFileRefDone), ctypes.py_object(self))
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense to me. Part of the problem is that we don't know what `setCallback` does and we also don't know what `cbFileRefDone` is. Your code doesn't reference `myCallback` after defining it.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function appears to be a C function with prototype:

```
void __stdcall Callback(uint32)
```

You don't need to do anything special to be able to access `self`. The `ctypes` magic arranges that for you. The code you need is something like this:

```
class MyClass():
    def myMethod(self):
        def myCallback(p1):
            print "Callback called!"
            # self is available here

        callback = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_void_p, 
            ctypes.c_uint32)(myCallback)
        somedll.setCallback(callback, 0)
```